# Display ASP.net WebAPI Documentation in different MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

In my solution, I've two projects. One ASP.Net WebAPI with several controllers and actions and another an MVC5 application. When navigating to /Help route of WebAPI project itself, the documentation is rendering fine.

The goal is to show the same documentation from the MVC application (MVC is the front-end and WebAPI is UI-less).

I've referenced API assembly and added namespace of it to the `RouteCollection` in the MVC application; and, copied the necessary views to MVC application. The Help controller itself is showing fine.

The issue is, `Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer().ApiDescriptions` collection is empty. My guess, ApiExplorer is searching in the MVC assembly and not in the API assembly.

I tried defining my own `IAssembliesResolver` as follows:

```
public class ApiAssemblyResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var controllersAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        return new [] { controllersAssembly };
    }
}
```

and then tried to set it in the `HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)` controller (in API assembly) as follows:

```
public HelpController(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new ApiAssemblyResolver());
    Configuration = config;
}
```

ApiDescriptions collection is empty.

First of all, is what I'm trying to do even possible? If yes, how should I go about achieving this?

**Update**
The trouble seems to be in `HttpConfiguration`. `ApiExplorer` goes off of `_config.Routes` which is empty when starting from MVC application.

Comment: Just a question, if the /Help perfectly works as part of the web API, from the MVC app, you can simply redirect the user to that Url when they want see the documentation or even show that page in an iframe within your MVC app view.

Comment: Problem with that is, mvc and api are different applications under IIS. And, business requires that this API Help Documentation is protected resource; shown only after authentication.